# PHP response mixed with previous response and output as plain text

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

We are running Apache 2.2.16 and PHP 5.3.3 with DomPDF to generate PDFs. After generating a PDF, the subsequent request occasionally returns a plain text response consisting partially of the HTML used to generate the PDF (i.e. from the previous request), mixed with the HTTP headers and response of the requested page.

Apache is somehow mixing part of the response to the previous request with the new response. It seems like an output buffering issue, although I cannot replicate it locally using the same code. It also seems unrelated to gzip, as the problem still occurs with it disabled. I also tried in both Firefox and Chrome and experienced the same result.

**UPDATE:** If I turn keep-alive off, it solves the problem. However, I don't necessarily want to leave keep-alive off. There is obviously still an underlying problem with the output buffer or response not being cleared.

Here are the request headers:

```
Request URL:https://asdf.com/checkout/5d86a9bdf455cdfd334494183559bf
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:APP=636c8e6b58e991476ed7d38849bde0d4; _
Host:asdf.com
Referer:https://asdf.com/get_pdf/33711
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.34 Safari/536.11
```

And the truncated response shown in the browser:

```
<!-- truncated HTML from the previous page (i.e. PDF) -->
    </p>
</div>


</body>
</html>HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 19 Jun 2012 18:06:13 GMT
Server: Apache
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 6457
Keep-Alive: timeout=7, max=96
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

‹í]ksÛ¸’ýìü
Œfvm×ÆzP/?µëØNâÄI<‘’ìL*å‚HHBD
Z–gæ¿o7@I-BNrkë~ÐÜ;c‰<xtŸF£›lŠÇ¿œ¿;ëüq}Aj’ëÏ®.ÏHa¯TúT=+•Î;çä_vÞ\‘J±L:’F1W\D4,•.ÞHa Ôø°TšL&ÅIµ(d¿Ôy_ºÃ¾*Ø8ý¸§¬–Å@…Ö“c=àÝ(Œâ“ÝTLke4h=Ù:V\…¬õ{"‹Éßä2RLR_ñ[FN}_$‘âQÿ¸d`€1E  v¾Ç¾%üö¤p& I¤ö:Ó1+ß|;)(v§J8ØñTÆL$ª··_ ¥ÖqìK>VDA“ù•ÞRs´@bé›ùÇ ýJïŠ}!ú!£c}1ÒÇJ!ïÆ¥¯ß&§¥J±™~,ŽxTüZÇ
<!-- followed by a bunch more gzipped gibberish -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure sounds like a problem with the webserver, in part caused by the `keep-alive` connection. Possible remedies:

- Send a `Content-Length` header with the PDF if you don't already. Also, make sure the `Content-Length` is *correct*: i.e: there is no more output after that.
- Disable `KeepAlive` in apache. Problem is this is cannot be done on a per-request or even per-directory basis as far as I know, so that would mean disabling if for you whole site (not recommended), or serve the pdf from a different virtual host.

My preference *definitely* goes to the first option if that solves it, the second one is cumbersome.

Comment: Wow just added an update related to keep-alive before you posted this  :) i

Comment: The Conte-Length header was already being set (appears to be correct, as the size matches the size of the PDF). Any other ideas? My only other thought is to set the keep-alive timeout to 1. It wouldn't completely solve the problem, but it won't occur unless you issue another request immediately after receiving the response... hmmm...

Comment: Hm, but there is HTML output. Could it be that the `Content-Length` is actually _incorrect_ and there is more output generated / sent after the bytes mentioned (i.e: some minor bug generates more output after the pdf is sent)?

Comment: You are right, CakePHP was trying to render the view after the PDF output was sent. I added an exit call immediately after streaming the PDF and that fixed the issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to be of help. This 'incorrect content-length creates weird output'-knowledge may come in handy some day ;)